Correction of Minor Errors in a Published Research Paper
As a current PhD candidate, I was delighted to have published my first paper two years ago in a journal during my doctoral studies. Subsequently, I left that research group and joined a new one, along with a new supervisor. Recently, while reviewing my previously published work, I discovered several minor errors in that paper.
To be precise, there are three such errors:

In the main text, a parameter used for calculation was incorrectly stated. This error, however, does not affect any subsequent calculations or the principal conclusions of the paper. Additionally, this parameter was cited from another reference, which is clearly indicated. Thus, readers can refer to that paper to obtain the correct value.

In the supplementary materials, a simulation parameter was incorrectly listed in a table, though the value I actually used in the simulations was different. Upon discovering this mistake, I carefully rechecked the calculations and confirmed that due to the precision of the model, this discrepancy does not affect the simulation results. Both values are widely used in the literature and are valid.

The video accompanying the paper does not match the content of the article. Specifically, the version of the video that was published is an earlier draft and should have been updated to reflect the phenomena described in the paper. This might confuse readers, as the demonstration shown in the video does not correspond to the events discussed in the text.


The first two errors are merely typographical and do not affect any data or results. However, the discrepancy in the video might lead to some confusion, as the visual demonstration differs from the text.
We discovered the error in the main text before publication. I brought it to my former supervisor’s attention, but it seems that while correcting other mistakes, this one was inadvertently overlooked. As for the video, I had sent my supervisor the updated version via email, but apparently, it was not uploaded. The error in the supplementary materials was entirely my own oversight. In short, these errors stemmed from both my and my former supervisor’s oversights.
I have already consulted my current supervisor, who advised me to reach out to my former supervisor (the corresponding author of the paper). I contacted him, but he has not responded. I am unsure whether this is because he considers these errors trivial or if he is upset that I pointed out two of the mistakes were his responsibility. (At the time of submission, my supervisor handled the entire process, and I did not thoroughly check the materials uploaded to the submission system.)
As such, I am uncertain about how to proceed. Should I wait for my former supervisor’s response, or should I directly contact the editor to request a correction? Although this paper is unrelated to my current PhD research topic, I am concerned that these minor errors may negatively impact my progress towards obtaining my degree. I also feel ashamed of my own oversight.

Did you put reasonable effort into contacting your PhD advisor? Many academics routinely overlook single e-mails. This sounds like a great opportunity to call up your PhD advisor and catch up.

@Joooeey   I have made every effort to contact him, including phone calls and emails, but I still haven't received any response. I would like to meet with him in person, but even the colleagues I worked closely with in the research group are unsure of his whereabouts; they only know that he is still assigning tasks to his students. I am beginning to suspect that he may be intentionally not replying to me.

If you haven't been contacted by anyone about these errors, then there is really no need to bother. If you've been read and cited, people have overlook or corrected for the minor errors.
You can, of course, contact an editor at the journal and ask for a solution. Perhaps they can make a correction online, or provide an errata page.
If you have your own web-site, you can also publish errata there.

Thank you very much for your detailed and helpful response！

The best end result would be to publish a corrigendum in the same journal where the original article was published. For this, it would be best to have your former supervisor, the corresponding author, involved. Some authors don't like to publish corrigenda, viewing it as a mark against them. Some authors prefer to include remarks in subsequent papers pointing out the errors in the earlier work. Personally, I think it's best to publish a corrigendum, so try harder to get in touch with the former supervisor, e.g. by calling if email doesn't work. You might need to convince him/her.
Lastly, if you're in a field that uses arXiv, you can fix the errors and update the arXiv preprint so that at least new readers who get your work from there will get the right version. But, that creates a conflict with the published version, so it's still important to eventually get in touch with the journal. By the way, if the editor views the errors as very minor, they might decline to publish a corrigendum.

I greatly appreciate your comprehensive and thoughtful answer.

The first two errors almost certainly do not need correcting, because they do not affect the overall conclusions of the paper.
The issue with the video may be worthy of correcting - it's not possible for us to say.
If you are the first and/or corresponding author, you could consider reaching out to the editor of the journal, explaining the situation re the video, and taking their advice. Otherwise, I would stick with what you have already done.

Thank you very much for your reply! As the first author of the paper, I will follow your advice. While waiting for the corresponding author’s response, I will reach out to the editor directly.
